# Python Eve embedded document query

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

Is there a way I can query the embedded document in python eve?
For example: I have following response:
URL: http://127.0.0.1:5000/shipments/57fafd5bb9211367f5b2006e

```
{
    "_updated": "Mon, 10 Oct 2016 02:30:51 GMT",
    "track": "57fafd5bb9211367f5b2006d",
    "ref_no": "268771821909",
    "_created": "Mon, 10 Oct 2016 02:30:51 GMT",
    "_id": "57fafd5bb9211367f5b2006e",
    "_etag": "af5af366b7dba18456be6112c59172b1dfe21593"
}
```

Below is the response when embedded document is set to 1:
URL : http://127.0.0.1:5000/shipments/57fafd5bb9211367f5b2006e?embedded={"track":1}

```
{
"_updated": "Mon, 10 Oct 2016 02:30:51 GMT",
"track": {
    "_updated": "Mon, 10 Oct 2016 02:37:57 GMT",
    "tracks": [
        {
        "status": "MS",
        "remark": "None",
        "datetime": "Mon, 10 Oct 2016 02:30:51 GMT"
        },
        {
        "status": "DP",
        "remark": "Not Good",
        "datetime": "Mon, 10 Oct 2016 02:31:51 GMT"
        }
        ],
    "_created": "Mon, 10 Oct 2016 02:30:51 GMT",
    "_id": "57fafd5bb9211367f5b2006d",
    "_etag": "9eac811c400d9c8a9507ae83988daeb5a5ec5c6c"
    },
"ref_no": "268771821909",
"_created": "Mon, 10 Oct 2016 02:30:51 GMT",
"_id": "57fafd5bb9211367f5b2006e",
"_etag": "af5af366b7dba18456be6112c59172b1dfe21593"
}
```

Tracks Schema:

```
schema = {
    'awb_number' : {'type' : 'string'},
    'tracks'     : {'type':'list',
            'schema' : { 'type':'dict',
            'schema'   : {
            'status'   : {'type':'string', 'allowed': STATUS},
            'remark'   : {'type':'string', 'allowed': REMARK},
            'datetime' : {'type':'string'},
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Now I want to query the `status` of last element in the `tracks` array.
Something like this in Python:

```
if tracks[-1]['status'] == 'DP': print 'Do this'.
```

But I'm not sure how I can query the same in URL.

Comment: `schema[''tracks'']["status"]`  should get you there, you cannot index dictionaries with an order as the are un-ordered collection.

Comment: tracks is a list because of that I'm trying tracks[-1] which will get me the last element of the list (which will be a dictionary) and then I'm trying to get value of 'status' key : tracks[-1].status but not sure if we can do the same in URL

Comment: tracks[-1]["status"]

Answer (score 0):

> I want to query the status of last element in the tracks array. Something like this in Python

You need to get the response of what you queried after all the database interaction and embedding(if any). You can achieve that by adding an [event hook](http://python-eve.org/features.html#database-event-hooks).

You can try something like

```
def do_something_with_result(resource, response):
    '''
       resource: contains who called (in your case, shipments probably)
       response: the data which you get back after the fetching
    '''
```

The response will be a dictionary which contains the data, where you can search for `track`. Now this function needs to be added to the current flask app as an event.

```
from flask import current_app as app

app.on_fetched_item += do_something_with_result
```

Note that, this will be triggered after every item being fetched. If you want specifically for one particular resource `on_fetched_item_<resource_name>`. Then the signature of the former function changes to `do_something_with_result(response)`

Comment: Hi @BineethMohan, could you please add more detail to your answer? If you're unsure please check the help center for getting help on [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Updated the answer. Do provide a feedback as this is my first answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and this works.

```
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['test']
collection = db["interests"]

r=collection.find({})
for data in r:
    for i in data['mylist']:
        if i['status']=='no':
           print("done")
```

My schema for interests looked like this:

```
interests={
'cache_control': 'max-age=10,must-revalidate',
'cache_expires': 10,
'schema':{
    'interest':{
        'type':'objectid',
        'required':True,
        'data_relation': {
            'resource': 'works',
            # make the owner embeddable with ?embedded={"owner":1}
            'embeddable': True
        },
    },
    'mylist':{
        'type':'list',
        'schema':{
            'type':'dict',
            'schema':{
                'myfield':{
                    'type':'string'
                },
                'status':{
                    'type':'string'
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this solves your issue..